# FOSUserBundle 2.1.0 - How to handle updated controlers? Save to use Bundle inheritance?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

My `Symfony 2.8` based project currently uses `FOSUserBundle` v2.0.2 and `Composer` proposes an update to the latest version 2.1.2.

As far as I can see the [releases from 2.0.2 to 2.1.2](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/releases) do not contain BC breaking changes. However v.2.1.0 includes:

> Refactored controllers and commands **to use DI**. Projects extending these classes will need to adapt their code (but should rather use supported **extension points** when possible).

**What is DI?**

I have created a custom `MyUserBundle` bundle which extends the `FOSUserBundle` using **bundle inheritance**.

`MyUserBundle` overrides some of the parent `FOSUserBundle` controllers to customize the behavior. It is sufficient to check signatures (param lists) of the overridden methods inside these controllers and update them if necessary, o**r are there any other steps necessary to make this work with v2.1.0?**

**What is meant with 'extensions points'?** How could they be used to replace the bundle inheritance?

Comment: DI = Dependency Injection PS: I never used FOSUserBundle

Comment: You really want to stay away from 2.1.x, especially if you don't have a good understanding of dependency injection.  If you look at the [controller's construct signature](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/v2.1.2/Controller/ChangePasswordController.php), you will find that a number of dependencies are now being injected directly instead of being pulled from the service container.  This will mess you up big time unless you know how to work around it.  Lock your version to 2.0.  There are a number of other questions on this same topic.